# Can I send disappearing SMS on android device?

Tags: java, android, sms, one-time-password, self-destruction

Is there anyway send a message which is not saved in the receivers message box and is removed after reading once?

I searched on google and find something like self-destructing message. 
https://www.mashnol.org/self-destructing-text-message-app/
But its not what I am looking for.

I received an SMS which had an EditText attached to it, and once I replied or not the message was destroyed from memory as it was not recorded.

Is there anyway I can achieve something like this??

Comment: This is not possible. You either deleted / archived the message accidentally or you have a bug with your phone

Comment: No. Its not possible, unless the phone has a messaging app developed by you, and it is set as the default messaging app and you know which message to delete once read by the user.